# Get new result in infinite loop with SqlAlchemy

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlalchemy, infinite-loop

I'm new to Python - coming from PHP - and have been bouncing back and forth between Python official documentation and SqlAlchemy (which I'm trying to use as easily as Laravel's DB class)

I have this bit of code:

```
from sqlalchemy import *
engine = create_engine('mysql://root:pass==@aws.com/db')
db_connection = engine.connect()
meta = MetaData()
video_processing = Table('video_processing', meta, autoload=True, autoload_with=engine)

while True:
    sleep(1)
    stmt = select([video_processing]).where(video_processing.c.finished_processing ==  0).where(video_processing.c.in_progress == 0)

    result = db_connection.execute(stmt)

    rows = result.fetchall()


    print len(rows)

    stmt = None
    result = None
    rows = None
```

When I execute my statement, I let it run and print out the number of rows that it fetches.
While that's going, I go in and delete rows from my db.
The problem is that even though I'm resetting pretty much everything I can think of that is related to the query, it's still printing out the same number of fetched rows in every iteration of my loop, even though I'm changing the underlying data.
Any ideas?

Comment: @egekhter I would think you would need to update the engine and reconnect every time there are changes.

Comment: Okay - I placed db_connection = engine.connect() inside the loop and that gave me the expected results. Coming from PHP land, the logic doesn't quite make sense in that I am only executing my query at step db_connection.execute(stmt) , and obviously we're not downloading all the tables' data until we execute the statement, so I must be missing something.

Answer (score 2):

The tricky part is that the connection needs to be closed if using engine.connect() with db_connection.close() otherwise you might not see new data changes.

I ended up bypassing the connection and executing my statement directly on the engine, which makes more sense logically anyways:

```
result = engine.execute(stmt)
```